# Entity Framework - Update database manually

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

I am new to entity framework and using EF 6.1.1... using code first approach i have generated the database..

When i run my application from Visual Studio in my local machine..

and update a record from my application.. it immediately reflects in ui immediately..

but if i update the records in database manually.. then the changes are not reflected immediately  in ui.. i need to rebuild the solution to and run it again to bring the updated data to ui..

Just need to know if this is how entity framework works?? if yes, is there a way to make the ui to sync with database even for manual updates without rebuilding the solution..

Please let me know if you need any other information..

Comment: Is this a desktop application? What's the lifetime of your DbContext?

Comment: As per @jrummell it is likely your context is stale. Shorten the lifespan, or [disable caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking(v=vs.103).aspx) on your queries.

Comment: Code please. We have no idea what you are doing and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.. This is a web application..  I believe data retrieved by linq queries are getting cached. How to disable caching/ shorten the lifespan on specific queries?